# @TypeChecked failure over generic type argument

Tags: generics, groovy

I have a mixed groovy/java environment with a simple Manager hierarchy:

```
public abstract class HomeBean<T extends BaseEntity> {
    private T instance;

    public T getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            if (id != null) {
                instance = loadInstance();
            } else {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    protected void setInstance(T instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
}
```

and in TaskManager.groovy:

```
@TypeChecked
class TaskManager extends HomeBean<Task> implements Serializable {
    void doSomething() {
        instance.compute()
    }
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the groovy compiler assumes that `instance` is of type `BaseEntity` and simply ignores the restriction made by `TaskManager`.

Is this by design or can I somehow make the compiler aware of the additional type information?

Edited to add: I've verified this is still happening with groovy-2.1.7, despite my hope it would be fixed in [GROOVY-5981](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5981).

Edited to add: As a workaround, I'm casting the instance like this:

```
@TypeChecked
class TaskManager extends HomeBean<Task> {
    void doSomething() {
        currentTask.compute()
    }

    Task getCurrentTask() { instance as Task }
}
```

But that's a needless piece of duplication I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: I reopened GROOVY-5981

Comment: @blackdrag So I take it that's not by design? Wanna make that an answer pointing to the bug?